# Useful to use two numbers for a hashing function

Tags: c, hash

I've come across the following code for creating a basic (tutorial) hash for an input string:

```
/* Internal Hashing functions
 */
static unsigned get_hash_internal(const char* s, int number, int num_buckets)
{
    long hash=0;
    size_t len_s = strlen(s);

    for (int i=0; i < len_s; i++) {
        long number_to_power = (long) pow(number, len_s - (i+1));
        hash += number_to_power * s[i];
    }

    return (unsigned) (hash % num_buckets);
}

static unsigned get_hash(const char* s, int num_buckets, int attempt)
{
    unsigned hash = get_hash_internal(s, NUMBER_1, num_buckets);
    if (attempt != 0)
        hash += attempt * (get_hash_internal(s, NUMBER_2, num_buckets) + 1);
    return (unsigned) (hash % num_buckets)
}
```

My questions is what difference it makes to use two primes here -- `HT_PRIME_1` and `HT_PRIME_2` in this function? Would there be any disadvantage of just using `HT_PRIME_1` for both?

Comment: Use unsigned types while hashing. Forget the function: it is bogus.

Comment: @wildplasser what's wrong with the function? Or it's just a toy hash function and doesn't really provide a uniform distribution or anything like that.

Comment: I think the reason for using two primes is so that the two hashes aren't correlated.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by 'correlated' ?

Comment: The hash function is used to get an index into an array. If that element is already filled, it's a collision. So we call the hash function again to get another index to try. We repeat this until we find an empty slot. The two different primes keep the repeated attempts from being just multiples of the original.

Comment: When `num_buckets` stays the same on collision, seems quite inefficient to `ht_get_hash(..., ..., 0)`, then on collision `ht_get_hash(..., ..., 1)`, etc. as `hash_a = ht_hash(s, HT_PRIME_1, num_buckets)` is repeated called when only one call is needed.  Further only one call of `ht_hash(s, HT_PRIME_2, num_buckets);` is needed rather than a re-call due to another collision.

Comment: "what difference it makes to use two primes here -- HT_PRIME_1 and HT_PRIME_2" --> without showing `ht_hash()`, it is guess work.  Post the code of `ht_hash()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica updated the code for it.

Comment: Your code doesn't use HT_PRIME_ at all; but cut to the chase.   Modulo prime to seed a re-hash guarantees a walk of the table based on the initial hash; thus provided your hash table isn't full, you will eventually find either a matching or empty slot.  Rather than believe me, or lookup a bloodless reference on discrete math; try it using very simple numbers and a small prime to observe the walk.

Comment: `(long) pow(number, len_s - (i+1));` is problematic as `pow()` readily make a value outside the `long` range leading to undefined behavior.  With 64-bit `long` its will favor making value with lower bits 0.  Consider an non-FP hash.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what do you mean by non-FP? Isn't long not a floating point?

Comment: @carl.hiass `double pow(double)` is a FP function.